# Как сделать сортировку списка в Android?

Tags: java, android, сортировка

У меня в приложении есть список сообщений (входящие и исходящие) и я хочу их сортировать по возможности по трем параметрам: текст сообщения, отправитель и тема. Если никакой сортировки не выбрано то просто выводить список всех несортированных сообщений.

Эта сортировка будет находится в Spinner где будут все параметры сортировки. Я нашел способ сортировки. Но у меня получается сортировать только по одному параметру, например по отправителю, а мне нужно сделать так чтобы была возможность менять фильтр. Вот что я нашел:

Класс для сортировки:

```
public class DateSort implements Comparator <Message> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Message message, Message t1) {
        return message.getSender_name().compareTo(t1.getSender_name());
    }
}
```

и дальше вот как его использовать для сортировки:

```
List<DataEntity> data= new ArrayList<DataEntity>();
DateSort ds = new DateSort();
try{Collections.sort(data, ds);}
catch(Exception es){};
```

все работает так как нужно, но есть один вопрос - нужно ли мне будет создавать несколько классов сортировки для того чтобы сделать все нужные мне фильтры или же можно сделать все в пределах одного класса? Потому-что я вот пробовал создавать еще один метод `compare` для других параметров и у меня не получилось.

Может у кого-то есть более нормальный метод сортировки списка, буду рад если любым советам и помощи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Да, вам лучше будет создать разные классы для разных сортировок.
- Если вам надо сортировать по нескольким полям за раз, то можно использовать: `thenComparing`. Вот примерный код:

  ```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Comparator;

  class Person {
      int age;
      String name;

      @Override
      public String toString() {
          return "Person{" +
                  "age=" + age +
                  ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                  '}';
      }
  }

  class CompareByAll implements Comparator<Person>{

      @Override
      public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
          return o1.age - o2.age;
      }

  }

  class CompareByName implements Comparator<Person>{

      @Override
      public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
          return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
      }

  }


  public class teTCompare {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          teTCompare qwe = new teTCompare();
          Person p1 = new Person();
          p1.age = 10;
          p1.name = "123";
          Person p2 = new Person();
          p2.age = 10;
          p2.name = "223";
          Person p3 = new Person();
          p3.age = 10;
          p3.name = "323";
          Person p4 = new Person();
          p4.age = 10;
          p4.name = "023";
          Person p5 = new Person();
          p5.age = 50;
          p5.name = "-123";
          ArrayList<Person> asd = new ArrayList<>(5);
          asd.addAll(Arrays.asList(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5));

          asd.sort(new CompareByAll().thenComparing(new CompareByName()));

          System.out.println(asd);

      }

  }
  ```

Результат будет:

```
[Person{age=10, name='023'}, Person{age=10, name='123'}, Person{age=10, name='223'}, Person{age=10, name='323'}, Person{age=50, name='-123'}]
```