# Непонятная проблема с выбором элемента spinner Android

Tags: java, android, сортировка, android-spinner

Пытаюсь внедрить `spinner` у себя в приложении. В списке есть три пункта, и по непонятной мне причине воспринимается выбор только 2,3 если начинать отсчет с 1. Вот мой предыдущий вопрос по этой теме - [Как сделать сортировку списка в Android?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/886084/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-android). Вот что у меня получилось на данный момент:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
switch (position) {
case 0:
messageArrayList = (ArrayList<Message>) Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getMessages();
adapter = new ListAdapter(messageArrayList, getActivity(), type);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
break;
case 1:
DateSort_theme ds = new DateSort_theme();
try {
messageArrayList = (ArrayList<Message>) Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getMessages();
adapter = new ListAdapter(messageArrayList, getActivity(), type);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
Collections.sort(messageArrayList, ds);
} catch (Exception ignored) {
}
break;
case 2:
DateSort_sender ds2 = new DateSort_sender();
try {
messageArrayList = (ArrayList<Message>) Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getMessages();
adapter = new ListAdapter(messageArrayList, getActivity(), type);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
Collections.sort(messageArrayList, ds2);
} catch (Exception ignored) {
}
break;
}
```

вроде все одинаковое у всех пунктов но почему-то выбирается только 2,3. А я хочу сделать, чтобы по умолчанию был выбран 1 пункт и дальше уже смотреть если 1,2,3 выбирается то что-то делать. Пробовал вставить еще дополнительно `default` в блоке `switch` но он тоже не выбирает по-умолчанию и вообще не видно что он работает. Наверное у меня где-то ошибка но не могу понять где именно.

### UPDATE

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
if (response.isSuccessful()) {
Integer count = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getCount();
if (count > 0) {
recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
/* messageArrayList = (ArrayList<Message>) Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getMessages();
adapter = new ListAdapter(messageArrayList, getActivity(), type);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);*/
spinner.setSelection(0);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
switch (position) {
case 0:
messageArrayList = (ArrayList<Message>) Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getMessages();
adapter = new ListAdapter(messageArrayList, getActivity(), type);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
break;
case 1:
DateSort_theme ds = new DateSort_theme();
try {
messageArrayList = (ArrayList<Message>) Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getMessages();
adapter = new ListAdapter(messageArrayList, getActivity(), type);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
Collections.sort(messageArrayList, ds);
} catch (Exception ignored) {
}
break;
case 2:
DateSort_sender ds2 = new DateSort_sender();
try {
messageArrayList = (ArrayList<Message>) Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getMessages();
adapter = new ListAdapter(messageArrayList, getActivity(), type);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
Collections.sort(messageArrayList, ds2);
} catch (Exception ignored) {
}
break;
default:
messageArrayList = (ArrayList<Message>) Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getMessages();
adapter = new ListAdapter(messageArrayList, getActivity(), type);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
break;
}
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
spinner.setSelection(2);
messageArrayList = (ArrayList<Message>) Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getMessages();
adapter = new ListAdapter(messageArrayList, getActivity(), type);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
}
});

} else if (count == 0) {
recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
ivPicture = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.ivNoMess);
ivPicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Где ты вызываешь spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener это onCreate? Ты должен в методе onCreate задавать spinner.setSelection(0); как только создается окно, спиннер должен применить выбранный пункт, в данном случае первый

Comment: нет это не в onCreate(), это функция которая используется для послания запроса, и уже в этой функции в зависимости от результатов с сервера идет работа с данными.

Answer (score 1):

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           // Тут вешаешь Switch
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
           // Тут выполняешь код, если ничего не выбрано, например код первого кейса
        }
    });
```

Вообще Switch должен срабатывать у тебя, так как position по умолчанию равна 0, тут возникает вопрос где ты устанавливаешь слушателя на spinner? Слушатель должен быть установлен в onCreate

Comment: слушатель у меня стоит в функции, которая получает данные с сервера, если сервер ничего не прислал то слушатель не работает :(

Comment: Ну тогда как код из Spinner должен сработать, если слушатель не реализован изначально? Ты слушатель установи в onCreate spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); а в Swtich установи методы, первый по умолчанию, а остальные работают только если от сервера есть ответ

Comment: так первый тоже может работать только если есть от сервера ответ, без ответа он бессмысленный

Comment: все-равно не получается то что нужно, чем мне дополнить вопрос, чтобы вам легче было мне помочь?

Comment: Там, где ты делаешь проверку на ответ от сервера, поставь условие, если ответ не пуст spinner.setSelection(0); таким образом ты будешь вызывать первый пункт из списка.

Comment: так этот пункт всегда по-умолчанию ставится, или нет? просто мне по дефолту нужно чтобы при выбранном 0 итеме список заполнялся сообщениями несортированном виде, а уже потом после выбора какого-то пункта меню я бы получал на выходе сортированный список.

Comment: обновил вопрос, добавил весь код что я использую для решения этой задачи.