# Помогите решить проблему с spinner android

Tags: android, сортировка, android-spinner

Я задавал уже здесь вопрос по этой теме - [Непонятная проблема с выбором элемента spinner Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/886115/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-spinner-android). Код у меня практически не изменился, но на всякий случай я прикладываю весь код который я использую для обработки ответа сервера. Этот код находится не в функции onCreate() а в отдельно созданной функции которая вызывается из onCreate():

```
mAPIService.get_list_of_messages("Bearer " + a_token, type, 1).enqueue(new Callback<MessageArray>() {
@Override
public void onResponse (@NonNull Call < MessageArray > call,@NonNull final Response<MessageArray> response){
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        Integer count = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getCount();
        if (count > 0) {
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                    switch (position) {
                        case 0:
                            DateSort_time dsor = new DateSort_time();
                            try {
                                messageArrayList = (ArrayList<Message>) Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getMessages();
                                adapter = new ListAdapter(messageArrayList, getActivity(), type);
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                Collections.sort(messageArrayList, dsor);
                            } catch (Exception ignored) {
                            }
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            DateSort_theme ds = new DateSort_theme();
                            try {
                                messageArrayList = (ArrayList<Message>) Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getMessages();
                                adapter = new ListAdapter(messageArrayList, getActivity(), type);
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                Collections.sort(messageArrayList, ds);
                            } catch (Exception ignored) {
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            DateSort_sender ds2 = new DateSort_sender();
                            try {
                                messageArrayList = (ArrayList<Message>) Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getMessages();
                                adapter = new ListAdapter(messageArrayList, getActivity(), type);
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                Collections.sort(messageArrayList, ds2);
                            } catch (Exception ignored) {
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                }
            });
        } else if (count == 0) {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ivPicture = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.ivNoMess);
            ivPicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
}
```

проблема в чем - у меня есть spinner в котором есть три пункта, 0,1,2 эти пункты отвечают за сортировку писем в моем приложении. По-умолчанию я хочу сделать чтобы открывался пункт 0, что означает - письма отображаются без сортировки в свободном порядке, дальше если я выбираю либо 1 либо 2 пункт, у меня происходит сортировка по фильтру. По какой-то непонятной мне причине у меня работает выбор только 1,2 пункта а 0 вообще ничего не показывает, чисто гипотетически можно создать фильтр и для 0 пункта, чтобы например сортировалось по дате, но все-таки хочется сделать так чтобы при открытии активити был выбран 0 пункт и сообщения отображались нормально. Можно конечно все перекинуть в функцию onCreate() но вопрос в том почему у меня работает нормально 1,2 пункт а 0 вообще не принимается.

### UPDATE

вот попробовал перекинуть все в onCreate() и все-равно 0 элемент не грузит ничего, походу проблема не в функции а в спиннере.

Надеюсь что поможете найти мою ошибку.

Comment: А я могу вас попросить поменять местами логику 0го и 2го пункта и посмотреть, что будет? Просто если у вас как-то неправильно работает dsor. А с учетом того, что вы никак не обрабатываете исключения, то может просто что-то не видите.

Comment: логику вы имеете в виду, это просто поменять то что делает 0 и 2?

Comment: Ну да - просто посмотреть, а на самом деле у вас `case 0` не работает.

Comment: ок я вас понял, сейчас попробую, но я вот пробовал toast закинуть и по-моему все нормально показывало, а вот список не выводит, но сейчас попробую поменять

Comment: @Axenow, я попробовал поменять 0 и 1 вместо 0 и 2, я думаю что сильно большой разницы нету, но все-равно ничего не работает, 0 тупо ничего не показывает

Comment: А когда вы поменяли 0 и 1, то что было раньше в 0 - начало работать в 1?

Comment: да, начало работать

Comment: Значит, дело не в коде - а в не могли бы проверить, там значения возвращаемые - реально с 0 начинаются? я понимаю, что бред, но кто знает. Потому что если все так, то я тогда не знаю в чем именно дело. )

Comment: для проверки я решил использовать обычный тост, и короче при запуске активити тост не выводится, если потом выбрать например 1 или 2 все нормально, а после этого если опять выбрать вручную 0, то тост выводит. Но по-умолчанию если открывать активити, то ничего не выводит, почему-то при старте активити не выбирается 0 и даже если тост показывается то все-равно список сообщений не выводит

Comment: А вы уверены, что у вас по-умолчанию вообще 0 выбрано? Где и как вы это задали?

Comment: ну я это пробовал задавать в onCreate() через setSelection() , но это ни на что не повлияло, поэтому я забил на эту затею

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так и не найдя решения здесь, и после продолжительных поисков в интернете, я решил сделать совсем страшно но во всяком случае работающий вариант. Я убрал выбор нулевого элемента, хотя это не очень правильно, и дальше я сделал чтобы после того как приходит ответ с сервера с сообщениями, я просто их вывожу до слушателя спиннера, а в самом спиннере я просто смотрю были ли выбраны 1 и 2 второй элемент. Я знаю что это очень неправильно так делать, но по-другому ни у меня ни у других я так понимаю не получилось, поэтому решил сделать так. Если у кого-то все-таки возникнут идеи, то буду рад их выслушать.

Comment: _Совсем страшно_ - это то что Вы впихнули это всё в `onResponse`, тогда как инициализация UI должна вызываться в `onCreate`. Список изначально должен отображаться в дефолтной или выбранной ранее сортировке, а спиннер после переключения юзером просить адаптер сменить сортировку. А адаптер и должен её реализовывать и предоставлять метод(ы) управления ею. P.S. Не знаю откуда вообще повелось создавать и сеттить адаптер после получения и тем более изменения данных - это не правильно, лучше использовать один экземпляр, созданный при инициализации UI, чем на каждый чих создавать новый.

Comment: То есть лучше отправлять запрос из onCreate()??

Comment: При чём тут запрос? По результату запроса нужно лишь отдать сообщения в адаптер и сменить видимость UI, не надо туда громоздить половину логики приложения

Comment: Но вся проблема Вашего вопроса в непонимании того, что слушатель вызывается только тогда, когда юзер делает выбор, а при установке слушателя никакой дефолтный код не выполняется. Чтобы он выполнился нужно после установки слушателя просеттить нужный элемент `spinner.setSelection(0);` (по идее слушатель должен отреагировать, но это не точно:).

Comment: честно говоря не очень понимаю вас @woesss, если я правильно понял нужно каким-то образом все переместить в функцию `onCreate()`и там поставить выбор `spinner.setSelection(0);`? просто я сейчас тоже не очень понимаю каким образом у меня работает все вроде как нужно, но по логике все это (запрос, спиннер) не нужно делать в одной функции которая все-равно вызывается из `onCreate()`.